# Determining maximum font size for UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to determine maximum font size for `UITextView` which keeps all texts inside without cropping, while its containing text is already set and constant.

**Note**: I'm using custom fonts, and Swift.

Comment: Do you need to get a number? You can use "Autoshrink" property of uitextfield, where you set whether u want to shrink by setting minimum font size, or scale it by value

Comment: I just need the number, I won't set the max font size, user does and i want to limit it to the max font size.

Comment: Mhm, Vizllx answer is one way of doing it, but you may do it by calling  boundingRectWithSize to see what is the rect of next font increase iteration.. if that height/width is bigger than your textfield, you disable control, that increase font size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void)ff
{
    int minSize = 12; //define a minimum font size
    int maxSize = 60; //define a maximum font size
    int size = minSize;
    for (size = minSize; size < maxSize; size++) {
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"your_font_name" size:size]; // init your font
        textView.font = font;
        [textView.layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:textView.textContainer];
        NSRange visibleRange = [self visibleRangeOfTextView:textView];
        if (visibleRange.length < textView.text.length) {
            size--;
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%d", size);

    return YES;
}

- (NSRange)visibleRangeOfTextView:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGRect bounds = textView.bounds;
    UITextPosition *start = [textView characterRangeAtPoint:bounds.origin].start;
    UITextPosition *end = [textView characterRangeAtPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds))].end;
    return NSMakeRange([textView offsetFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument toPosition:start],
                       [textView offsetFromPosition:start toPosition:end]);
}
```

For the best results I suggest you to reset textview's paddings:

```
[textView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
```

Comment: Would you please convert it to Swift?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't learn swift yet. So you must convert it yourself

Answer (score 0):

First determine Max and Min font size:-

```
static const CGFloat MAX_SIZE = 12.0;
static const CGFloat MIN_SIZE = 7.0;
```

Secondly in viewDidLoad() set maximum font size

```
self.txtVw.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:MAX_SIZE];
```

Thirdly in textView delegate method write the following code:-

```
- (void)textDidChange:(UITextView*)textView
{
    // This will  to adjust this sizing as per your requirement.

    self.txtVw.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:MAX(
        MAX_SIZE - textView.text.length, 
        MIN_SIZE
    )];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Calculate height of the content .Then resize your frame.

```
CGSize strSize= [textView.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(290.0,99999.0)];
frame.size.height = strSize.height
```